# Update plots in different tabPanels with one action button Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In a bigger app I am building I have a situation where I need to update multiple plots in different tabPanel using one action button.

Now, the updating of the plots after pressing the action button works.
However, if I go back to a previous tabPanel, I would like to work with the cached value in dataNorm or dataUnif to still be able to update the title of the plot.

Situation:

1. Click go to view Uniform hist
2. Update Unif hist title
3. go to plotNorm tabPanel
4. Click go to view Normal hist
5. Update Norm hist title
6. go back to plotUnif tabPanel (dont click go!)
7. Try to update title...

Any help would be very much appreciate!! :)

Below you see the example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            tabsetPanel(id = "tabset",
                        tabPanel("plotUnif",
                                 numericInput("unifCount", "Count", 100),
                                 sliderInput("unifRange", "Range", min = -100, max = 100, value = c(-10, 10)),
                                 textInput(inputId = 'titleUnif', "Change Title"),
                                 plotOutput("plotUnif")
                        ),
                        tabPanel("plotNorm",
                                 numericInput("normCount", "Count", 100),
                                 numericInput("normMean", "Mean", 0),
                                 numericInput("normSd", "Std Dev", 1),
                                 textInput(inputId = 'titleNorm', "Change Title"),
                                 plotOutput("plotNorm")
                        )
            ),
            actionButton("go", "Plot")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            "Bla"
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output){
    
    # Record how many times go has been pushed
    v <- reactiveValues(go_rec = 0L)
    
    # Compute new dataUnif only if input$go in new and on that tab (wanted effect: otherwise return cached value)
    dataUnif <- eventReactive(input$go,{
        shiny::req(input$go > v$go_rec, input$tabset == "plotUnif", cancelOutput = T)
        
        v$go_rec <- input$go
        return(runif(input$unifCount, input$unifRange[1], input$unifRange[2]))
    })
    
    # same as dataUnif
    dataNorm <- eventReactive(input$go,{
        shiny::req(input$go > v$go_rec, input$tabset == "plotNorm", cancelOutput = T)
        
        v$go_rec <- input$go
        return(rnorm(input$normCount, input$normMean, input$normSd))
    })
    
    # Disply hist (be able to change title)
    output$plotUnif <- renderPlot({
        shiny::req(dataUnif())
        hist(dataUnif(), main = input$titleUnif)
    })
    
    output$plotNorm <- renderPlot({
        shiny::req(dataNorm())
        hist(dataNorm(), main = input$titleNorm)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You should look at the `update*` functions provided by `{shiny}`, e.g `shiny::updateTextInput()`

Comment: Unfortuntely, adding a title is just an example here. In the more complex app there are all kinds of reactive calculations and subsetting happening between dataUnif/dataNorm and the renderPlot statements.

Comment: Okay but there many `update*` functions. It is hard to imagine something where putting these updates in an `observe` environment wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

To have title plots refreshed without clicking on `actionButton`, you need to unblock the `req` when the plots have been drawn once. A solution is to save their state in the `reactiveValues`

```r
  # Record how many times go has been pushed and which plot has been plotted once
  v <- reactiveValues(go_rec = 0L,
                      go_Unif = FALSE, 
                      go_Norm = FALSE)
  
  # Compute new dataUnif only if input$go in new and on that tab or plot already done)
  dataUnif <- eventReactive(input$go,{
    shiny::req(input$go > v$go_rec || v$go_Unif, input$tabset == "plotUnif", cancelOutput = T)
    
    v$go_rec <- input$go
    v$go_Unif <- TRUE
    return(runif(input$unifCount, input$unifRange[1], input$unifRange[2]))
  })
  
  # same as dataUnif
  dataNorm <- eventReactive(input$go,{
    shiny::req(input$go > v$go_rec || v$go_Norm, input$tabset == "plotNorm", cancelOutput = T)
    
    v$go_rec <- input$go
    v$go_Norm <- TRUE
    return(rnorm(input$normCount, input$normMean, input$normSd))
  })
```

Comment: Thanks HubertL, this works indeed. Just that now the runif and rnorm still compute even if I did change the count or parameters. (in my real scenario these two computations represent very expensive comps). I wanted to achieve a way to use a cached value if the count or parameters didnt change, while still updating a filter (or change the title in the example)

Comment: Probably easier to put an action button in each panel